# chicken egg problem

Tags: correlation, linear-model, hidden-markov-model, cross-correlation

I should run a test to determine whether variable A affect variable B or viceversa.

What type of test should I use?

Imagine that we measure the time slept per night (A) and the activity performed during a day (B) in several subjects. In particular we have a median of 4 nights and 4 days measured for each subject.

How would you approach the problem?

```
1) estimate how much the night (A) is correlated with the following day (B)
2) estimate how much the day (B) is correlated with the following night (A+1)
3) take the highest correlated condition
```

Is there a test that takes into account this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Pure correlation won't help you with this. Have a look at [Granger causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality).

Comment: @A.Donda would it work even if my timeseries are not so extended? I have data for 4 days and 4 nights...

Comment: @A.Donda please have a look at the edited question. In particular, I have a median of 4 assessed nights and days for each subject studied. Should I assess the Granger causality for each subject? Should I use a "bag of words approach", i.e. I put all the timeseries of all the subjects together?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... are you saying you do not have values for 4 different nights and days, but just the median? In that case you don't have a timeseries, and neither your approach or my suggestion work. Or what is the median across? – Assuming you do have a timeseries, yes, it is possible that you do not have enough data to properly fit a Granger causality model (AR model) to the data. But in that case, as far as I can see, you simple cannot answer your question using your data. How much data you need also depends on the order of the AR model that you fit; maybe order 1 is enough...

Comment: Putting the timeseries of all subjects together is an option, but it has consequences for inference. What you are doing then is effectively a "fixed effects model", which means you can test for a statistically significant effect only for your sample, but you cannot generalize to the population of samples. In principle it would be better to analyze each subject's data separately and then apply a "second-level" to the estimated indices of directionality of causality, but if you don't have enough data you simply can't do that.

Comment: @A.Donda thanks for your answer. I have the subjects assessed for 4 days in median, so I do have a small time series for each subject. Nevertheless what I am interested at is the effect that night has to the day "globally"...do you have time to discuss it in a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28873/discussion-between-a-donda-and-gabboshow).